# Global challenge in Temple Run 2

Tags: temple-run-2

Global challenges have stopped appearing for me. I have an objective to complete 10 global challenges.
Level 13.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, not getting Global Challenges seemed to be a symptom of not having the latest update.  But for the last month or so (since early August 2017, I believe) there haven't been any Global Challenges appearing on any of my devices, which are completely updated.  Perhaps the Global Challenge is on a summer vacation and maybe it will return soon!

Edit: they were working on a Fall Jungle update and the release of Sept 1 has a Global Challenge, first in multiple weeks.